# login to Django with URL?

Tags: django

Is it possible to login to Django by passing the username/password in the URL?
I am using https to communicate to my server and I need a remote machine to access some raw text via a django view. So I am hoping I can just make a user for this remote machine, and login via the url. Or is there a better way of automatically logging in? Most of the other posts I have read talk about using the DjangoREST framework, and using a API token to get the data via JSON, but this would mean I need to store all the text on the database and create new models etc etc. I would rather just serve this text with a regular django view and HTML template.

Comment: You're confusing a few things. The method of authentication is independent of the way you serve your final document. You can pass an Authorization token in your HTTP headers and still return an HTML document. The problem is that it sounds like your view would be a GET request, but you first need to login that remote user, which has to be a POST request because it's an action that changes the database state. You should really consider adding an authentication token backend, so your remote user can first login and fetch the token and then use the token for all subsequent requests.

Comment: And yes, you can write a view that receives a POST request with the username and password in the query parameters (the view can get them from `request.GET` even if it's a POST request) and then authenticates the user using the default Django authentication backend and then returns the document.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @dirkgroten: Basically I want a very simple view, just returning some text when the view receives a `get` request, but I don't want this visible to anonymous users. The machine sending the `get` request doesn't have a human using it, so it can't login with a form (sorry I'm quite new at web development!) so my thought was I could pre-program the credentials into the `get` request url. Sounds like that is possible as per your second comment. I will dig into it more. Thanks again

Comment: “Login with a form” is just a HTTP POST request with some data. A script can do this as well as a human. You can create a python script that sends the login form data, receives the session cookie and then submits the get request for your view with the cookie. That way you don’t have to change anything on the Django side.

Comment: Ok I will give that a try! Thanks for the help and suggestions @dirkgroten